# What is the correct way to include a unicode character in the querystring of a WCF request?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, encoding, unicode

I have a query string parameter that maps to a string, and it needs to include the [broken bar](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a6/index.htm) character, `¦`.  I tried percent-encoding it as `%A6`, but it's coming through as this `�`, with a numeric value of 65533.

Is there a way to either encode it differently or change the settings of my WCF service so it will interpret the character correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer.  It needs to be encoded as `%C2%A6`, since `C2A6` is the UTF-8 encoding for the broken bar in hexadecimal.

Edited to add:

I believe that this is always the correct URL encoding for the character (not just a requirement of the WCF service).  For instance, see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16).

[This page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) led me to use the wrong encoding, but [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) did it correctly.